# What should be right behavior when we're trying to instantiate a template?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct A
{
    int a = A<1>::a;
};


int main() { }
```

Is invalid for **[CLANG](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3b08b3f6a7ec5c8)**, but valid for **[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8d203f2379ba814)**. What behavior is actually correct? The Standard wasn't pretty clear about that:

`N4296::14.7.1/1 [temp.inst]`

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 5):

This is invalid code, because `A<1>` has incomplete type at the point of usage. Your quote from the standard is not relevant (`A<1>` cannot be instantinated at the point of usage).

The situation would be different if instead you had

```
template<int> struct A;
template<> struct A<1> { static int a; };
template<> struct A<2>
{
  int a=A<1>::a;                    // fine: A<1> has complete type
};
```

Moreover, in your original code, what do you think that the value of `A<1>::a` or `A<0>::a` should be? Nowhere is there a way to assign a value to it. You claim that gcc compiles this, but what's `A<1>:a`? garbage? null?

---

As R Sahu pointed out in the comments, your code also suffers from the fact that you cannot access the member `A<1>::a` without an object (unless it's a `static` member).

---

Regarding the access to members.

In the code referred to by your comment, the member was accessed implicitly as member of the object `*this`. Thus within class `A<1>` (or any derived classes), `A<1>::a` is the same as `this->a`. But outside you must provide an object.

Comment: You can't do that unless `A<int>::a` is a static member variable.

Comment: @RSahu Not quite clear why. We're getting access inside the initializer of the non-static member.

Comment: The RHS of the initialization statement cannot be `A<1>::a` unless `a` is a static data member of `A<1>` or `A<1>` is a parent class of `A<2>`.

Comment: @RSahu But in any way, `Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, using-declarations introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes).` So the class type is complete at the point if usage, isn't it?

Comment: @RSahu Moreover it's possible to use non-statics data member in the way I cited in my post. Look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c06cb1d2910e348) . I'm confused...

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, I don't have an answer to the first question. Regarding using `A::b` in your example, that is same as `int a = b;` since the statement is inside the class. When you have explicitly specialized `A<1>`, `A<1>::a` can be used by `A<2>` only if  `A<1>::a` is a static member of `A<1>` or `A<1>` is super-class of `A<2>`. I think you know that.